# Execution Error in Greedy Gift Givers USACO Training program

Tags: c++, execution

I'm taking a computer coding class in high school this year and I am trying to do Greedy Gift Givers(http://cerberus.delosent.com:791/usacoprob2?a=2uhftHpQUHa&S=gift1). I turned it in and got an execution error that said:

> "Execution error: Your program did not produce an answer
>           that was judged as correct. The program stopped at 0.005 seconds;
>           it used 3496 KB of memory. Your answer length was 119; the correct
>           length is 121. At character number 21, your answer says '1' while
>           the correct answer says '5'."

I'm almost done, and it gives four answers out of ten correctly. I don't know how to fix it. One of my friends told me to check my variables and I did, but all of them are correct as far as I know.

The new code reads:

```
/*
ID              :   aknorth1
PROB            :   gift1
LANG            :   C++
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE=10;

    int groupSize, numReceivers, giveAway;
    int bankAcct[ARRAY_SIZE];
    string giver, receivers;
    string groupPeople[ARRAY_SIZE];

    ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
    ifstream fin ("gift1.in");

    fin >> groupSize;

    for (int j=0; j<groupSize; j++)
    {
        fin >> groupPeople[j];      
        bankAcct[j]=0;
    }

    for(int x=0; x<groupSize; x++)
    {
        fin >> giver;
        fin >> giveAway;
        fin >> numReceivers;
        for (int j=0; j<numReceivers; j++)
        {
            if (giver == groupPeople[j])
            {
                bankAcct[j] -= giveAway;
                if (numReceivers != 0)
                {
                    bankAcct[j] += (giveAway % numReceivers);
                }
            }
        }   
        for(int j=0; j<numReceivers; j++)
        {
            fin >> receivers;

        for (int q=0; q<groupSize; q++)
            if (groupPeople[q] == receivers)
            {
                if (numReceivers != 0)
                {
                    bankAcct[q] += (giveAway / numReceivers);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<groupSize; j++)
    {
        fout << groupPeople[j]<< " " << bankAcct[j] << endl;
    }                   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In all your loops, instead of `ARRAY_SIZE`, you should be using `groupSize`.

Comment: The problem definition should be included in the question, at least the basics. If the definition of the problem is too long, then provide a link to the problem definition (with at least a basic description in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't follow the specs for input format.

```
fin >> giver; // dave
fin >> giveAway; // gives away 200
fin >> numReceivers; // to 3 receivers

for (int j=0; j<numReceivers; j++)
{
    if (giver == groupPeople[j]) // if dave was 4th in the list then what?
        {
            bankAcct[j] -= giveAway;
            if (numReceivers != 0)
            {
                bankAcct[j] += (giveAway % numReceivers); // giver gives to himself?
            }
        }
    }
```

There might be more of it, stopped at this.